# creating cross platform application

Tags: c#, mono, cross-platform

I was making an **OpenGL** application with **C#** and **Windows Forms**.

Recently I thought about making it cross-platform, I mean to make it run on **Windows**, **Linux** and **OS X**. I have never even tried to make a cross platform application.

I did some research and found that I should use mono. Do applications made with MonoDevelop will run fine all of these platforms without any additional installations? If not, what exactly user will need to install to run that application?

Is there any easy way to write the code once and then build it for windows, linux and os x without requiring the additional installations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does applications made with MonoDevelop will run fine on windows, linux, os x without any additional installations?

Well. They will require Mono to be installed on Linux and OsX and the corresponding version of the .NET framework on Windows (or Mono there too).

When developing, you will of course need to keep cross platform concerns in mind (directory separators, for instance, though the `Path` class helps here), and Mono have created the migration analyzer to help with this - see [MoMa](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA).

Now, assuming you kept these in mind and that Mono and or the .NET framework is installed on the end user system, you shouldn't need anything additional to install.

Comment: Mono doesn't necessarily need to be installed. The framework can be statically linked to the application (although it does require a commercial license)